# How to store the result of find in bash array, to use result as file path in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, find

When using the following command within a bash array, it loses the line separation of the array elements.

```
array=$(find "${PWD%/*}" -name '*.dmg')
```

If I redirect the path of the find command, without storing it in a variable, but storing it to a text file, it gives the desired result.

```
find "${PWD%/*}" -name '*.dmg' > Out.txt
```

But I would like to use the result as a variable in Bash and to loop through it.
In this case the find command should return an array with the path of all .dmg files in a directory. I want to loop through this array with the `hdiutil` mount command in order to mount all the `.dmg` files in the directory.

Comment: Please format code next time, this tiem I made the edits.

Comment: Thank you will do. This is my second post in stack overflow, I am still learning how to interact here. But thank you for the improvement.

Comment: Well no problem AFouquet, welcome!

Comment: You aren't defining an array at all; you are just capture the output of `find` as a single string.

Comment: Also, you are assuming (maybe with good reason) a file name won't contain a newline itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapfile` to safely transfer your found files into an array.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -a array

mapfile -d '' array < <(find "${PWD%/*}" -name '*.dmg' -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

`find -print0` option produces null delimited strings so spaces, tabs and carriage return in file names are preserved safely.

`mapfile -d '' array` reads `stdin` with a null delimiter to populate `array`

`< <(commands group)` injects the commands group's output into the `stdin` of the other commands group.

The result is, that the output of `find` is mapped into `array`.

For older Bash 3.2 from MacOS lacking `mapfile`, here is an alternate way to populate `array`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env/bash

declare -a array

while read -r -d ''; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find "${PWD%/*}" -name '*.dmg' -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: I will try it out, will get back to you, after I get the result.
Thank you :)

Comment: Just learned that I don't have the mapfile command in OSX. I will have to find an alternative to this. I probably could download it with homebrew, than every system where the script should run would have to install it first in order for it to work.

Comment: @AFouquet If you want something that works on any macOS system, consider writing this in `zsh` instead.

Comment: @chepner I am very new to scripting in general. What are the advantages of using zsh?

Comment: It's mainly designed with interactive usage in mind. However, for your purposes, its main benefit is that even versions of `zsh` that ship with older versions of macOS (and some version has shipped with macOS for a very long time, though I don't have any reference for what shipped when) provide more "continuity" of features with modern `zsh` than you see with `bash` 3 vs `bash` 4.x.

Comment: Put another way: the chances of an appropriate version of `zsh` (that can easily support reading the output of `find` into an array) being preinstalled on your target machines is greater than an appropriate version of `bash`.

Comment: @AFouquet  I added an alternative method compatible with Bash 3.2 from MacOS

Comment: @chepner I will definitely look in to zsh. Thank you.

Comment: @LéaGris Will also try out your alternative thank you. I'll let you know as soon as I get a result. Thank you for the support. :)

Comment: Note that in `zsh` or recent enough `bash`; you don't need `find`; `array=( $PWD/**/*.dmg )` would suffice. (And `zsh` globs have enough bells and whistles that can replace even complicated uses of `find`.)

Comment: @LéaGris Hi, I have finely completed my scrpit. It's not perfect yet, but it does what it is supposed to. Thank you for your help. Here is the github Link if you would like to check it out and give me some feedback. I would really appreciate it. 

https://github.com/afouquet7/Bash-.dmg-Installer/blob/release/TheInstallator_v1.3.command